# tools:replace in android manifest doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I have an activity that changes depending on the flavour
main flavour ;
 `<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />`

my second flavour:
   `<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" tools:replace="android:screenOrientation" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />`

but when a I run the second flavour I always get the activity in portrait mode,it ignores the landscape I set on the manifest

the tools:replace doesn't seem to be working